# ReferenceError: module is not defined in Jasmine Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am begining with Angular and with unit testing, this is my first code, and it isn't working. I searched  for a solution but I dont know what I am doing wrong. If anyone can explain to me what is the mistake, I would thank you.

This is all my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="boot.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jasmine.css">

</head>

<body  ng-app = "myApp">

<div ng-controller = "MyCtrl">
{{greeting}}
</div>
<br><br><br>

<script>

    <!-- CODE -->

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello World!';
    }]);

    <!-- JASMINE -->

    describe('myApp', function () {
        var scope,
        controller;
        beforeEach(function () {
            module('myApp');
        });

        describe('MyCtrl', function () {
            beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                    '$scope': scope
                });
            }));
            it('sets the greeting', function () {
                expect(scope.greeting).toBe('Hello World!');
            });

        });
    });

    describe('JavaScript addition operator', function () {
        it('adds two numbers together', function () {
            expect(1 + 2).toEqual(3);
        });
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you meant to type `angular.module('myApp')` in your `beforeEach` function.

Comment: That remove the "ReferenceError: module is not defined" but the "ReferenceError: inject is not defined" remains. what can I do for that particular mistake? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to load Jasmine *before* loading Angular. Move your `<script>` tags for `jasmine.js` and `jasmine-html.js` above the one for angular. That's how `angular-mocks.js` detects the testing environment. After that, you can just use `module` instead of `angular.module` again.

Comment: it didn't change the status. _"ReferenceError: inject is not defined"_ remains and by moving the <script> tags of `jasmine` and `jasmine-html` above the ones of `angular` and `angular-mock` it doesn't allow me to remove the **angular**.module. @MikeC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of your scripts is wrong. You should first include the scripts related to Jasmine, and then the scripts for angular and angular-mocks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!--Scripts for Jasmine-->
<script src="jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="boot.js"></script>

<!--Script for Angular-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<!--Scripts for Angular-Mocks-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jasmine.css">
</head>

<body  ng-app = "myApp">

<div ng-controller = "MyCtrl">
{{greeting}}
</div>
<br><br><br>

<script>

<!-- CODE -->

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello World!';
}]);

<!-- JASMINE -->

describe('myApp', function () {
    var scope,
    controller;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
    });

    describe('MyCtrl', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));
        it('sets the greeting', function () {
            expect(scope.greeting).toBe('Hello World!');
        });

    });
});

describe('JavaScript addition operator', function () {
    it('adds two numbers together', function () {
        expect(1 + 2).toEqual(3);
    });
});
```