# Module is not a function Angular + Jasmine Unit testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am coming across this error when trying to make sure jasmine testing works for my angular app:

> TypeError: Module is not a function

Here is my jasmine.json

```
{
    "spec_dir": "spec",
    "spec_files": [
        "**/*[sS]pec.js"
    ],
    "helpers": [
        "helpers/**/*.js"
    ],
    "files": [
        "js/angular.js",
        "js/controllers.js",
        "js/angular-mocks.js"

    ],

  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": false
}
```

Here is my PlayerSpec.js:

```
describe("TicketCentralCtrl", function() {
 beforeEach(module('TicketCentralCtrl'));

});
```

First time using Jasmine, so I am probably missing something really obvious.

Comment: You might want to double check if the `js/angular-mocks.js` file actually exists in that location. The `module` method should be getting put in the global `window` from that library.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37671040/2622292

Comment: Angular-mocks.js is definitely there.  I don't think it's recognizing any of the references in the "files" key for some reason.  @SiddharthAjmera I am trying to run this test in a separate directory, not directly in my application.